# pandas adding data from index table to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `dataframe` `monthlyTempDiff` with contents as:

```
monthlyAdder.ix[1:3]
         City1     City2    City3
monthID                              
1        0.01      0.1      0.02
2        0.04      0.2      0.03
8        0.17      0.3      0.05
```

Column `monthID` is also the index.

I have another table `fwdTempTable`

```
fwdTempTable.ix[1:3]
             City1     City2    City3      City4        monthID
DateTime                                                   
2017-1-01    22        24       26         16           1
2017-8-01    23        25       27         17           8
2017-2-01    13        15       17         27           2
```

I want to add to `fwdTempTable`, data from `monthlyAdder` based on combination of `monthID` and `City1, City2, City3` to obtain the following:

```
fwdTempTable.ix[1:3]
             City1     City2    City3      City4        monthID
DateTime                                                   
2017-1-01    22.01     24.1     26.02      16           1
2017-8-01    23.17     25.3     27.05      17           8
2017-2-01    13.04     15.2     17.03      27           2
```

i.e. for each row of dataframe `fwdTempTable`, I extract the `City1, City2 or City3` category and map it along with `monthID` to dataframe `monthlyAdder`. After mapping to `monthlyAdder`, I will get the right adder for a city and a month. I adjust the city data in `fwdTempTable` with this adder for that month.

These dataframes are large and I can't think beyond for loop on each column of `fwdTempTable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try `set_index` and `add`:

```
fwdTempTable.set_index('monthID', append=True).add(monthlyAdder, fill_value=0).reset_index('monthID')
```

Output:

```
           monthID  City1  City2  City3  City4
DateTime                                      
2017-1-01        1  22.01   24.1  26.02   16.0
2017-8-01        8  23.17   25.3  27.05   17.0
2017-2-01        2  13.04   15.2  17.03   27.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df1.reset_index().set_index('monthID')
cdx=df1.columns.isin(df.columns)    
df1.loc[:,cdx]=df1.loc[:,cdx].apply(lambda x:df.loc[x.index,x.name]+x )
df1.reset_index().set_index('DateTime')

Out[215]: 
           monthID  City1  City2  City3  City4
DateTime                                      
2017-1-01        1  22.01   24.1  26.02     16
2017-8-01        8  23.17   25.3  27.05     17
2017-2-01        2  13.04   15.2  17.03     27
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fwdTempTable.add(
    fwdTempTable[['monthID']].join(monthlyAdder, on='monthID'), fill_value=0)

           City1  City2  City3  City4  monthID
DateTime                                      
2017-1-01  22.01   24.1  26.02   16.0        2
2017-8-01  23.17   25.3  27.05   17.0       16
2017-2-01  13.04   15.2  17.03   27.0        4
```